# Superset - Only first polygon of multipolygon is plotted in superset in deck.gl polygon

Tags: geojson, apache-superset, deck.gl

I am trying to use the deck.gl polygon chart in superset to display data on European countries. I have a database with one column for the metric and one for the geographic information (a geojson describing the geometry of my countries).

My problem is that for countries which have a multipolygon as a geometry, only the first polygon in the geometry is filled, the other ones stay blank.

I have made a short example with France, where the multipolygon first contains information on the geometry of Corsica and then on the geometry of the rest of France. When I create a chart in Superset, only Corsica is filled while the rest of France remains blank. It's even more surprising because in the deck.gl geojson chart, all of France is filled.

[Only Corsica shows up in superset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ4Ls.png)

Here is the geojson that I used as a test:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                9.35394,
                41.62148
              ],
              [
                9.3804,
                41.66826
              ],
              [
                9.4022,
                41.85867
              ],
              [
                9.4563,
                41.98489
              ],
              [
                9.54391,
                42.2274
              ],
              [
                9.52347,
                42.40026
              ],
              [
                9.49602,
                42.63238
              ],
              [
                9.46487,
                42.89577
              ],
              [
                9.41006,
                42.96443
              ],
              [
                9.35207,
                42.93648
              ],
              [
                9.29036,
                42.71963
              ],
              [
                9.10158,
                42.71268
              ],
              [
                8.91009,
                42.63238
              ],
              [
                8.76165,
                42.55906
              ],
              [
                8.59188,
                42.37445
              ],
              [
                8.67426,
                41.94877
              ],
              [
                8.8549,
                41.66826
              ],
              [
                8.79667,
                41.62148
              ],
              [
                8.8282,
                41.54631
              ],
              [
                9.20677,
                41.39771
              ],
              [
                9.35394,
                41.62148
              ]
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [
                2.54601,
                51.08938
              ],
              [
                2.29607,
                51.04019
              ],
              [
                2.09445,
                51.00052
              ],
              [
                1.60758,
                50.84078
              ],
              [
                1.57268,
                50.45467
              ],
              [
                1.64474,
                50.35041
              ],
              [
                1.55409,
                50.32782
              ],
              [
                1.59843,
                50.21074
              ],
              [
                1.37964,
                50.06512
              ],
              [
                0.26189,
                49.72828
              ],
              [
                0.16179,
                49.67025
              ],
              [
                0.08683,
                49.52042
              ],
              [
                0.26304,
                49.44805
              ],
              [
                0.27001,
                49.44724
              ],
              [
                0.27477,
                49.45319
              ],
              [
                0.30381,
                49.45176
              ],
              [
                0.33743,
                49.44994
              ],
              [
                0.35958,
                49.44983
              ],
              [
                0.37765,
                49.45096
              ],
              [
                0.38701,
                49.45231
              ],
              [
                0.40185,
                49.45445
              ],
              [
                0.42163,
                49.45906
              ],
              [
                0.43267,
                49.46222
              ],
              [
                0.43556,
                49.46322
              ],
              [
                0.46167,
                49.475
              ],
              [
                0.47628,
                49.48159
              ],
              [
                0.4832,
                49.48493
              ],
              [
                0.49374,
                49.48747
              ],
              [
                0.50122,
                49.48768
              ],
              [
                0.50962,
                49.48679
              ],
              [
                0.51324,
                49.48641
              ],
              [
                0.52123,
                49.48325
              ],
              [
                0.53,
                49.47727
              ],
              [
                0.54037,
                49.46847
              ],
              [
                0.54602,
                49.46368
              ],
              [
                0.56759,
                49.44542
              ],
              [
                0.58374,
                49.43535
              ],
              [
                0.59868,
                49.43179
              ],
              [
                0.61269,
                49.43293
              ],
              [
                0.61915,
                49.43226
              ],
              [
                0.6219,
                49.43089
              ],
              [
                0.61485,
                49.42816
              ],
              [
                0.6058,
                49.4269
              ],
              [
                0.59929,
                49.4272
              ],
              [
                0.59476,
                49.42754
              ],
              [
                0.58464,
                49.43027
              ],
              [
                0.58014,
                49.43221
              ],
              [
                0.57064,
                49.43738
              ],
              [
                0.55876,
                49.44693
              ],
              [
                0.53715,
                49.46437
              ],
              [
                0.52281,
                49.47669
              ],
              [
                0.51649,
                49.47994
              ],
              [
                0.50318,
                49.48202
              ],
              [
                0.49366,
                49.48081
              ],
              [
                0.48441,
                49.47829
              ],
              [
                0.47544,
                49.47421
              ],
              [
                0.46167,
                49.46846
              ],
              [
                0.42577,
                49.45347
              ],
              [
                0.40698,
                49.44641
              ],
              [
                0.37064,
                49.43895
              ],
              [
                0.36666,
                49.43848
              ],
              [
                0.34057,
                49.43446
              ],
              [
                0.33444,
                49.43352
              ],
              [
                0.30976,
                49.4311
              ],
              [
                0.29722,
                49.4299
              ],
              [
                0.26189,
                49.41945
              ],
              [
                -0.17847,
                49.28916
              ],
              [
                -0.95566,
                49.39005
              ],
              [
                -1.11959,
                49.32227
              ],
              [
                -1.26348,
                49.50228
              ],
              [
                -1.30294,
                49.66828
              ],
              [
                -1.86536,
                49.66974
              ],
              [
                -1.80033,
                49.40848
              ],
              [
                -1.61666,
                49.14887
              ],
              [
                -1.57496,
                48.81782
              ],
              [
                -1.50477,
                48.67907
              ],
              [
                -1.5711,
                48.6265
              ],
              [
                -1.78114,
                48.61603
              ],
              [
                -1.94089,
                48.67652
              ],
              [
                -2.09375,
                48.59415
              ],
              [
                -2.34458,
                48.66224
              ],
              [
                -2.51435,
                48.60775
              ],
              [
                -2.58436,
                48.58528
              ],
              [
                -2.69944,
                48.54835
              ],
              [
                -3.16526,
                48.86148
              ],
              [
                -3.54096,
                48.8077
              ],
              [
                -3.65915,
                48.65942
              ],
              [
                -4.04011,
                48.70134
              ],
              [
                -4.32404,
                48.66069
              ],
              [
                -4.67718,
                48.55202
              ],
              [
                -4.75314,
                48.42299
              ],
              [
                -4.70097,
                48.36089
              ],
              [
                -4.42657,
                48.31934
              ],
              [
                -4.4697,
                48.23812
              ],
              [
                -4.3338,
                48.13733
              ],
              [
                -4.54717,
                48.02284
              ],
              [
                -4.31949,
                47.83377
              ],
              [
                -3.52245,
                47.80533
              ],
              [
                -3.38348,
                47.68552
              ],
              [
                -2.80494,
                47.49644
              ],
              [
                -2.58436,
                47.50731
              ],
              [
                -2.51435,
                47.51077
              ],
              [
                -2.45848,
                47.448
              ],
              [
                -2.51191,
                47.37683
              ],
              [
                -2.48428,
                47.29792
              ],
              [
                -2.18872,
                47.25382
              ],
              [
                -2.16402,
                47.13261
              ],
              [
                -2.09375,
                47.09284
              ],
              [
                -1.98046,
                47.02872
              ],
              [
                -2.09375,
                46.9011
              ],
              [
                -2.14593,
                46.84232
              ],
              [
                -2.09375,
                46.80161
              ],
              [
                -1.9008,
                46.65108
              ],
              [
                -1.79042,
                46.49036
              ],
              [
                -1.38927,
                46.34098
              ],
              [
                -1.22213,
                46.27785
              ],
              [
                -1.1843,
                46.3136
              ],
              [
                -1.12529,
                46.31706
              ],
              [
                -1.07529,
                46.31999
              ],
              [
                -1.18552,
                46.18438
              ],
              [
                -1.09667,
                46.04079
              ],
              [
                -1.14044,
                45.88854
              ],
              [
                -1.19052,
                45.86503
              ],
              [
                -1.30978,
                45.98732
              ],
              [
                -1.34087,
                45.94393
              ],
              [
                -1.1958,
                45.70052
              ],
              [
                -0.83695,
                45.48787
              ],
              [
                -0.71483,
                45.32837
              ],
              [
                -0.77918,
                45.29686
              ],
              [
                -1.05352,
                45.51784
              ],
              [
                -1.14175,
                45.47845
              ],
              [
                -1.23105,
                44.79776
              ],
              [
                -1.11426,
                44.68332
              ],
              [
                -1.20843,
                44.61194
              ],
              [
                -1.25409,
                44.46764
              ],
              [
                -1.37393,
                44.05232
              ],
              [
                -1.52476,
                43.52959
              ],
              [
                -1.78598,
                43.35048
              ],
              [
                -1.7289,
                43.29609
              ],
              [
                -1.38927,
                43.25812
              ],
              [
                -1.38927,
                43.18649
              ],
              [
                -1.41898,
                43.127
              ],
              [
                -1.469,
                43.08307
              ],
              [
                -1.4397,
                43.04836
              ],
              [
                -1.38927,
                43.03557
              ],
              [
                -1.31021,
                43.07692
              ],
              [
                -1.12529,
                43.02743
              ],
              [
                -0.7245,
                42.92016
              ],
              [
                -0.69093,
                42.89774
              ],
              [
                -0.56942,
                42.8166
              ],
              [
                -0.31334,
                42.84936
              ],
              [
                -0.01216,
                42.69987
              ],
              [
                0.26189,
                42.69995
              ],
              [
                0.47776,
                42.70002
              ],
              [
                0.66013,
                42.69095
              ],
              [
                0.67004,
                42.80186
              ],
              [
                0.71454,
                42.8536
              ],
              [
                0.85822,
                42.82574
              ],
              [
                0.90645,
                42.81386
              ],
              [
                1.32265,
                42.71132
              ],
              [
                1.41059,
                42.63238
              ],
              [
                1.44257,
                42.60367
              ],
              [
                1.50547,
                42.63238
              ],
              [
                1.52727,
                42.64232
              ],
              [
                1.56476,
                42.63238
              ],
              [
                1.7861,
                42.57366
              ],
              [
                1.7258,
                42.5044
              ],
              [
                1.73101,
                42.4924
              ],
              [
                1.91639,
                42.4539
              ],
              [
                1.9858,
                42.40026
              ],
              [
                2.03522,
                42.36207
              ],
              [
                2.14453,
                42.40026
              ],
              [
                2.23482,
                42.43181
              ],
              [
                2.29607,
                42.41463
              ],
              [
                2.34727,
                42.40026
              ],
              [
                2.55336,
                42.34244
              ],
              [
                2.71484,
                42.40026
              ],
              [
                2.88352,
                42.46067
              ],
              [
                3.1748,
                42.43537
              ],
              [
                3.04791,
                42.58306
              ],
              [
                3.04624,
                42.63238
              ],
              [
                3.04051,
                42.80186
              ],
              [
                3.04341,
                42.83817
              ],
              [
                3.06688,
                42.99934
              ],
              [
                3.24052,
                43.21287
              ],
              [
                3.54929,
                43.31054
              ],
              [
                3.64482,
                43.38208
              ],
              [
                3.79704,
                43.44171
              ],
              [
                3.91391,
                43.51169
              ],
              [
                3.94986,
                43.5297
              ],
              [
                4.10108,
                43.55471
              ],
              [
                4.15988,
                43.51169
              ],
              [
                4.23028,
                43.46018
              ],
              [
                4.52787,
                43.44121
              ],
              [
                4.66734,
                43.36425
              ],
              [
                4.89313,
                43.4213
              ],
              [
                5.07058,
                43.33823
              ],
              [
                5.30359,
                43.33174
              ],
              [
                5.39994,
                43.21227
              ],
              [
                5.67188,
                43.17927
              ],
              [
                5.83112,
                43.06291
              ],
              [
                6.29353,
                43.10803
              ],
              [
                6.63763,
                43.17733
              ],
              [
                6.72264,
                43.3848
              ],
              [
                6.90039,
                43.44171
              ],
              [
                6.93133,
                43.48026
              ],
              [
                6.97737,
                43.51169
              ],
              [
                7.17128,
                43.64405
              ],
              [
                7.4157,
                43.72591
              ],
              [
                7.41028,
                43.72935
              ],
              [
                7.41283,
                43.73171
              ],
              [
                7.41338,
                43.73458
              ],
              [
                7.43736,
                43.75163
              ],
              [
                7.43925,
                43.74902
              ],
              [
                7.52983,
                43.78401
              ],
              [
                7.52208,
                43.88939
              ],
              [
                7.71424,
                44.06151
              ],
              [
                7.60291,
                44.14254
              ],
              [
                7.38429,
                44.12332
              ],
              [
                7.03666,
                44.23343
              ],
              [
                6.88743,
                44.36129
              ],
              [
                6.87458,
                44.52314
              ],
              [
                6.94844,
                44.65474
              ],
              [
                7.06576,
                44.71346
              ],
              [
                7.00892,
                44.83099
              ],
              [
                6.77927,
                44.89676
              ],
              [
                6.63005,
                45.10986
              ],
              [
                7.09651,
                45.23238
              ],
              [
                7.16302,
                45.40355
              ],
              [
                7.10472,
                45.46845
              ],
              [
                7.01186,
                45.51196
              ],
              [
                6.9809,
                45.62729
              ],
              [
                6.80237,
                45.77856
              ],
              [
                7.04489,
                45.92241
              ],
              [
                6.81706,
                46.15744
              ],
              [
                6.82106,
                46.42715
              ],
              [
                6.5013,
                46.44921
              ],
              [
                6.21955,
                46.31188
              ],
              [
                6.234,
                46.19711
              ],
              [
                5.95607,
                46.1321
              ],
              [
                6.12561,
                46.31723
              ],
              [
                6.14275,
                46.37156
              ],
              [
                6.064,
                46.41623
              ],
              [
                6.13811,
                46.55767
              ],
              [
                6.41006,
                46.75371
              ],
              [
                6.46001,
                46.85155
              ],
              [
                6.46357,
                46.93451
              ],
              [
                6.85891,
                47.16529
              ],
              [
                7.02351,
                47.33184
              ],
              [
                6.9374,
                47.37541
              ],
              [
                6.93919,
                47.4337
              ],
              [
                7.13035,
                47.50304
              ],
              [
                7.22318,
                47.43031
              ],
              [
                7.38089,
                47.43189
              ],
              [
                7.51091,
                47.50258
              ],
              [
                7.55516,
                47.56456
              ],
              [
                7.58904,
                47.58988
              ],
              [
                7.51985,
                47.66731
              ],
              [
                7.54599,
                47.74357
              ],
              [
                7.60253,
                47.96769
              ],
              [
                7.57729,
                48.11565
              ],
              [
                7.57792,
                48.12139
              ],
              [
                7.68071,
                48.25727
              ],
              [
                7.8225,
                48.60837
              ],
              [
                7.95963,
                48.71858
              ],
              [
                8.23263,
                48.96657
              ],
              [
                8.06841,
                48.99932
              ],
              [
                7.91065,
                49.04516
              ],
              [
                7.63565,
                49.05395
              ],
              [
                7.48184,
                49.1563
              ],
              [
                7.36876,
                49.16146
              ],
              [
                7.24649,
                49.11786
              ],
              [
                7.10107,
                49.156
              ],
              [
                6.92547,
                49.21381
              ],
              [
                6.78449,
                49.16084
              ],
              [
                6.72347,
                49.21883
              ],
              [
                6.55699,
                49.41921
              ],
              [
                6.3651,
                49.45957
              ],
              [
                5.89339,
                49.49694
              ],
              [
                5.81812,
                49.54631
              ],
              [
                5.73456,
                49.54569
              ],
              [
                5.47088,
                49.49724
              ],
              [
                5.39351,
                49.61711
              ],
              [
                5.15374,
                49.71793
              ],
              [
                4.96943,
                49.80183
              ],
              [
                4.87047,
                49.80954
              ],
              [
                4.80981,
                49.97182
              ],
              [
                4.85244,
                50.12701
              ],
              [
                4.7967,
                50.14868
              ],
              [
                4.6629,
                49.99427
              ],
              [
                4.43249,
                49.94162
              ],
              [
                4.23313,
                49.95783
              ],
              [
                4.14085,
                49.97876
              ],
              [
                4.20692,
                50.07977
              ],
              [
                4.18583,
                50.23726
              ],
              [
                4.02777,
                50.35833
              ],
              [
                3.71703,
                50.32706
              ],
              [
                3.67327,
                50.39708
              ],
              [
                3.65551,
                50.46174
              ],
              [
                2.54601,
                51.08938
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "FID": "FR"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm a beginner with geojson, but all forums I've seen until now only mention that the geojson should follow the right hand rule, which I've made sure of, and it displays correclty on [geojsonlint.com](https://geojsonlint.com) or [geojson.io](https://geojson.io)